# Swift Alamofire send XML request and receive XML response

Tags: ios, xml, swift, alamofire

Hi i'm making a move from Objective C to swift. I'm trying to send xml request and receive xml response. How we can do that with Alamofire. Seem only can do for JSON?

my end point: "https://prdesb1.singpost.com/ma/GetItemTrackingDetails"

my sample request body (xml) :

```
<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest xmlns="http://singpost.com/paw/ns">
<ItemTrackingNumbers>
<TrackingNumber>SMT0000000628</TrackingNumber>
</ItemTrackingNumbers>
</ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>
```

The response should be

```
<ItemTrackingDetailsResponse xmlns="http://singpost.com/paw/ns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ItemsTrackingDetailList>
        <ItemTrackingDetail>
            <TrackingNumber>SMT0000000628</TrackingNumber>
            <TrackingNumberFound>true</TrackingNumberFound>
            <AlternativeTrackingNumber/>
            <TrackingNumberActive>true</TrackingNumberActive>
            <PostingDate/>
            <InsuredValue/>
            <InsuredSDR/>
            <Weight/>
            <ExpressInd/>
            <ItemCategory/>
            <Content/>
            <PreadviceDate/>
            <ReceptacleID/>
            <OriginalCountry>Singapore</OriginalCountry>
            <DestinationCountry>Singapore</DestinationCountry>
            <ItemType>Speedpost</ItemType>
            <DeliveryStatusDetails>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Recovered item from POPStation for service recovery</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-22T16:35:30</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160822 163530</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Delivered to POPStation</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>POPStation@Yew Tee Square</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T17:27:48</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 172748</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>With Delivery Courier</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T11:25:00</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 112500</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Received at Processing Facility</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-16T10:28:07</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160816 102807</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
                <DeliveryStatusDetail>
                    <StatusDescription>Notification of shipment confirmation</StatusDescription>
                    <Location>SPEEDPOST SERVICE CENTRE</Location>
                    <BeatNo/>
                    <Date>2016-08-13T11:10:29</Date>
                    <AceDate>20160813 111029</AceDate>
                </DeliveryStatusDetail>
            </DeliveryStatusDetails>
        </ItemTrackingDetail>
    </ItemsTrackingDetailList>
    <Status>
        <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDesc>Success</ErrorDesc>
    </Status>
</ItemTrackingDetailsResponse>
```

Seem there is no default method to deal with XML body data. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

update: I have tried to use Almofire but still cannot get the correct response (got nil for parsed response). My server support SSLv3 and TLS 1.0 (have already enable transport securty)

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (NSError?)->Void

func fetchXML(url: String, trackingNumber: String, completion: CompletionHandler) -> Void {

let params = "<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest xmlns=\"http://singpost.com/paw/ns\"><ItemTrackingNumbers><TrackingNumber>\(trackingNumber.uppercaseString)</TrackingNumber></ItemTrackingNumbers></ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>"

    let xmlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)        
    xmlRequest.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    xmlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    xmlRequest.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    Alamofire.request(xmlRequest)
             .response { request, response, data, error in

                print("url\(request?.URL?.absoluteString)")
                print("requestBody\(request?.HTTPBody)")
                print(params)

                print("error\(error.debugDescription)")
                print("status code\(response?.statusCode)")
                let xml = XML.parse(data!)
                print(xml.text)

            }
}
```

and call from viewcontroller

```
let trackingItemUrl = "https://prdesb1.singpost.com/ma/GetItemTrackingDetails"

    self.networking.fetchXML(trackingItemUrl, trackingNumber: "SMT0000000628") { error in
        print("can we get here?")
    }
```

Comment: how we can deal wit xml request and response?

Comment: This is the XML response from Singapore Post I assume? The XML is badly designed since `Status` is placed at the end. You don't know the status until you've parsed everything

Comment: Yes this an old project in objective C. now want to make a move to swift. I'm having trouble with the request body and parsing response with xml data

Comment: Do you know how to get the response. I tried to use alamofire but dont know how to handle xml

Comment: I very much want to, but the endpoint gives me SSL certificate error and I don't have time to go through the SingPost API. Can you add the code where you make the request?

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with detail. My server support SSV3 and TLS 1.0 need to enable transport security