# swift contsruct a request with xml request body

Tags: ios, xml, swift

hi I'm about to create a custom request in swift

I'm having problem with my request body.

This my body in xml:

```
<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest xmlns="http://singpost.com/paw/ns">
<ItemTrackingNumbers>
<TrackingNumber>SMT0000000628</TrackingNumber>
</ItemTrackingNumbers>
</ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>
```

how to convert it to string and then data for the request?

I have try

```
let params = "<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>
        <ItemTrackingNumbers>
        <TrackingNumber>\(trackingNumber.uppercaseString)</TrackingNumber>
        </ItemTrackingNumbers>
        </ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>"

        let xmlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        xmlRequest.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        xmlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        xmlRequest.addValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

but have error in the params because i construct body String wrongly. Any way to construct String from xml above? any help is much appreciate. THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift doesn't support multi-line string literal yet and I haven't seen any proposal in the pipeline for that either. If you make that request a lot, it's better to wrap your request in a structure that builds the XML for you:

```
struct ItemTrackingRequest {
    var trackingNumbers: [String]

    init(trackingNumbers: String...) {
        self.trackingNumbers = trackingNumbers
    }

    func xmlString() -> String {
        var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        xml += "<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest xmlns=\"http://singpost.com/paw/ns\">"
        xml += "<ItemTrackingNumbers>"

        for number in self.trackingNumbers {
            xml += "<TrackingNumber>\(number)</TrackingNumber>"
        }

        xml += "</ItemTrackingNumbers>"
        xml += "</ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>"

        return xml
    }
}

let params = ItemTrackingRequest(trackingNumbers: "SMT0000000628").xmlString()
```

If you request gets complicated (like a lot more complicated), use Core Data to model the request and generate the XML for there.

Comment: thanks just figure out i have some space in my string construct which is typo error. The correct one should be let params = "<ItemTrackingDetailsRequest xmlns=\"http://singpost.com/paw/ns\"><ItemTrackingNumbers><TrackingNumber>\(trackingNumber.uppercaseString)</TrackingNumber></ItemTrackingNumbers></ItemTrackingDetailsRequest>"

Comment: Can help me take a look at this question. still struglling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318514/swift-alamofire-send-xml-request-and-receive-xml-response